# Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces"

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a netstandard2.0 library that is used by net5.0 applications
One of packages used by the library references Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces 5.0.0
But I get this warning for every application:

```
47>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2203,5):
 warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
    "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was not.
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [C:\Users\IgorBe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\1.1.1\ref\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll].
        C:\Users\IgorBe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\1.1.1\ref\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\IgorBe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\1.1.1\ref\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll".
C:\Users\IgorBe\.nuget\packages\microsoft.bcl.asyncinterfaces\1.1.1\ref\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
    References which depend on "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [].
```

Please note that "Project file item includes which caused reference" is not a project but the dll itself. My guess is that 1.0.0 version is used by compiler with .net standard to provide some core async functionality
But how can I get rid of this message? There seems to be no binding redirection for .Net 5.0

Comment: I don't know how to get rid of it, but you might get some more info from looking in your obj\project.assets.json file and searching for AsyncInterfaces.  In my case it showed up under "Azure.Core/1.24.0" (which is the latest at the time of writing) so I don't know what to do about that - is it a false warning?

Comment: For stuff like this I usually start by cleaning the project, and then manually removing any bin/obj folders. If that doesn't fix it, I'd try explicitly installing the Microsoft.Bcl.Interfaces nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue and could trace it to the inclusion of `IAsyncDisposable` resources.

I resolved the issue by manually disposing any `IAsyncDisposable` resources instead of using the `await using ...` notation.

Ex.:

```
public async Task MyFunction()
{
    await using var disposableResource = _factory.GetMyDisposableResource();
    // rest of code.
}
```

To

```
public async Task MyFunction()
{
    MyDisposableResource disposableResource = default!;
    try
    {
        disposableResource = _factory.GetMyDisposableResource();
        //rest of code
    }
    finally
    {
        if(disposableResource is not null)
            await disposableResource.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a terrible band-aid. I have to imagine there's a better solution.

Comment: I would be curious to know if the issue is still present when building a .Net Standard 2.1 library instead of a 2.0.

Comment: I would like to know why you would think of it as a terrible band-aid. The `Try..Finally` is basically what the `using` operator is converted to.

Comment: Using ten boilerplate lines of code, everywhere you use IAsyncEnumerable, to suppress a compiler warning that shouldn't be showing up, rather than addressing the root cause? That's a great example of a band-aid in my book. I know the behavior _should_ be identical, provided people always get the boilerplate code exactly right. But I think it has a very detrimental effect on the code's clarity and maintainability.